# Android Soap Envelope

Tags: java, android, soap

I am using ksoap in android to consume a soap based web service. Is there a way to find out the soap request formed by SoapSerializationEnvelope instance for checking if the request has formed properly or not.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - do you mean to check after you do this: SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

Comment: Thats correct Kristy, i want that only.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can extract soap request from SoapEnvelope

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeout);
androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
String requestString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
Log.d("Request in XML", requestString);
String response = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
Log.d("Response in XML", response);
```